# Non-System disk or disk error

Tags: linux, windows

I have Windows and Linux distributions on my `/dev/sda`.

I tried to install Fedora 13, but after reboot I cannot boot up to any of installed systems. I'm getting:

> Non-System disk or disk error
>
> replace and striky any key when ready

When I use Ubuntu 10, boot from first hard disk, I'm able to get GNU GRUB version 1.98... and boot up to any system. But without Ubuntu in a CD-ROM I'm getting this error.

I tried `grub-install /dev/sdX` in one of my installed Linux distributions, but without any success.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your BIOS isn't set to look at your hard drive.  Did you set it to boot from the cdrom for installation and forget to set it back?

Comment: I didn't have to change it, but I tried as well to modify order and set hard drive first or to pick it from menu. Unfortunately without success.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in installing ubuntu on a new SSD disk without any other OS. Installation was complete successfully but after a restart, I had encountered this error.
This problem was solved by connecting the SSD disk SATA cable to the SATA0 socket on the motherboard. This affects determining master/slave disk apparently.